# Как изымать List c помощью Hibernate?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hibernate

```
  public List<StopWordsDict> StopWords() {
        Session session = (Session) HibernateUtil.currentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<StopWordsDict> result = session.createQuery("from tbStopWordsDict").list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return result;
    }
```

Что неправильно? Подскажите, пожалуйста, не могу найти ошибку.

Comment: А в createQuery не нужен ли часом try-catch? ну, либо прокиньте исключения в шапку метода.

Comment: Our working language is Russian. Therefore please translate your question into Russian or move it to [intl. SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

session.getTransaction().commit(); - это лишнее, к тому же нужно закрыть сессию. 
Вот так будет нормально и типобезопасно:

```
public List<StopWordsDict> StopWords() {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        Query<StopWordsDict> query = session.createQuery("select s from 
        StopWordsDict s ", StopWordsDict.class);
        List<StopWordsDict> list = query.getResultList();
        session.close();
        return list;
}
```